# Does the controller-as syntax imply that view related code should be kept out of $scope?

Tags: angularjs

In strict server side MVC, the model should know nothing about the view, the two are separated from each other and the controller acts as an intermediary.

In Angular, the $scope object acts as a view-model, a data store for models that is loosely tied to the DOM. We may store other view related helper functions here. For example:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('carouselController', function($scope) {
    $scope.carousel = {
      current: 0,
      next:function() {
        current++;
      }
    };
  });
```

### Controller-as

The new controller-as syntax seems to imply that view helpers are not welcome in $scope objects, and that helpers should be assigned in a directive.

Is this indeed the road we are now travelling down.

Comment: In MVC, actions originate from the controller, services are called to retrieve the model, and then model is passed to the view for rendering.   The controller-as way of mediating the interaction follows the MVC pattern more closely, and maintains a better separation between the view, the model, and the controller.  If methods on $scope are used instead, then this separation is less clear - that is why AngularJS is sometimes referred to as an MV-Whatever framework, instead of a true MVC framework.

Comment: This is the case with strict MVC, however much of the fantastic productivity of Angular stems for the fact that we have this direct pipeline to squirt our models and view logic right into our front end. It seems to me that the real model lives on the server. What we refer to as a view is really just a template, and that the $scope object takes on the role of the view and temporary model store. I'd love a canonical opinion on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Controller-As syntax is a more explicit definition syntax.  In practice, it has always been recommended to "always have a dot" in controller variables.  (In other words, properties of an object on `$scope`, rather than properties of `$scope` itself.)  The Controller-As syntax is an explicit means to this end.

`$scope` still exists when using the Controller-As syntax; your "viewmodel" is automatically placed in `$scope` and bound to the controller explicitly.  It is therefore much more obvious where the values of your objects are being managed.  This is especially helpful in complex view scenarios where values could be set from multiple controllers.  Also, `$scope` isn't required to be injected unless you specifically need it for a specialty purpose like `$broadcast()`, which makes your code easier to read.

It should also be noted that `$scope` will be replaced with newer ECMA6Script features in Angular 2.0.  Using Controller-As will allow you to design controllers now which will be much closer to the new Angular 2.0 syntax, making the transition to Angular 2.0 (and the learning curve) much easier.

And yes, moving "view helper functions" to Directives whenever possible is the recommended path, and is evident with the new Component structure in Angular 2.0.

Another common path to take is for your helper functions to be either custom filter objects or encapsulated into a factory.

Comment: And presumably we instantiate these helpers in the directive link function?